# Unable to receive inputs from user

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

I am using quasar cli where I initialized my quasar project and included inputs fields in a form but when I try to submit a form the fields are sent as null in the console and in the payload. Below is the code I am using :

```javascript
<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { ref } from "vue";
import emailjs from "@emailjs/browser";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const email = ref("");
    const course = ref("");
    const fname = ref("");
    const phone = ref("");

    const error = ref(null);
    const isPwd = ref(null);

    const param = {
      fname: fname.value,
      email: email.value,
      course: course.value,
      phone: phone.value,
    };

    const handleSubmit = async () => {
      emailjs
        .send("service_id", "template_id", param, "public key")
        .then(
          (result) => {
            console.log("success", result.status, result.text, param);
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log("FAILED...", error.text);
          }
        );
    };

    return {
      handleSubmit,
      email,
      phone,
      error,
      isPwd,
      fname,

      course,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

Submitting a form and checking the fields in the console

Comment: What *event* triggers submission of the form? You know of course that your param object is filled with nulls and is non-reactive, and so will remain filled with null values.

Comment: You might also want to show your `<template>` code as well. I am no expert in this field of using forms with Vue, but when I've done this, I have "prevented" the submit button from performing its usual actions, using `@click.prevent="someActionMethod"` and instead gathered and submitted my form data in my own method, the `someActionMethod()` cited above. This way, I avoid the submission from re-initializing all the form fields, and this way I can filter the data before submission as I see fit.

Comment: In fact, I think that your problem is due to your use of non-reactive data, the param field, and that you're sending this data to your emailjs service. This won't work. Instead, consider making param reactive. It can even be a computed field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by moving param inside the handlesubmit function

```
<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { ref } from "vue";
import emailjs from "@emailjs/browser";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const email = ref("");
    const course = ref("");
    const fname = ref("");
    const phone = ref("");

    const error = ref(null);
    const isPwd = ref(null);


    const handleSubmit = async () => {
      
    const param = {
      fname: fname.value,
      email: email.value,
      course: course.value,
      phone: phone.value,
    };
      emailjs
        .send("service_id", "template_id", param, "public key")
        .then(
          (result) => {
            console.log("success", result.status, result.text, param);
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log("FAILED...", error.text);
          }
        );
    };

    return {
      handleSubmit,
      email,
      phone,
      error,
      isPwd,
      fname,

      course,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: Wrapping one's head around reactivity is hard, @Hover, especially for beginners. I'd also argue their solution is acceptable (although at that point `params` is redundant, they could place the object directly inside `.send()`, without assigning to a `const`). They likely need time. At some point they'll get tired of having to write `const`s and `.value`s and they'll start using `reactive`. Hopefully. Take comfort in knowing you explained what's going on and you have my appreciation. Keep up the good work!

Comment: @tao: likewise back to you!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem looks to be that you're sending in the param property when the form is submitted:

```js
emailjs.send("service_id", "template_id", param, "public key")
```

but param, which is defined here,

```js
const param = {
  fname: fname.value,
  email: email.value,
  course: course.value,
  phone: phone.value,
};
```

is not "reactive", it remains filled with the initial values of your reactive properties, null.

---

## One Option:

A better solution is to send in data that is in fact reactive. One way to do this is via a computed property.

For example:

```html
<template>
    <form action.prevent="sendStuff">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>My Form</legend>
            <div class="entry">
                <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" v-model="fname" id="fname" />
            </div>
            <div class="entry">
                <label for="email">EMail</label>
                <input type="email" v-model="email" id="email">
            </div>
            <button @click.prevent="sendStuff">
                Send Data
            </button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'

const email = ref("");
const fname = ref("");
// const course = ref("");
// const phone = ref("");

const param1 = {
    fname: fname.value,
    email: email.value,
    // course: course.value,
    // phone: phone.value,
}

const param2 = computed(() => {
    return {
        fname: fname.value,
        email: email.value,
        // course: course.value,
        // phone: phone.value,
    }
});

const sendStuff = () => {
    console.log('param1', param1);
    console.log('param2', param2.value);
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.entry {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    margin: 4px 2px;
}
</style>
```

Here, the first parameter property, param1, gathers data as you have been doing so, in a non-reactive way:

```javascript
const param1 = {
    fname: fname.value,
    email: email.value,
    // course: course.value,
    // phone: phone.value,
}
```

This data will not change despite a user's entering information into your form's fields.

The second parameter example, parame2, uses a computed property to gather the information held by the form's fields:

```js
const param2 = computed(() => {
    return {
        fname: fname.value,
        email: email.value,
        // course: course.value,
        // phone: phone.value,
    }
});
```

and here the data is reactive and changes when the user updates it.

---

## Second Option:

Another option is to encapsulate the model into one reactive property,

```js
const param3 = reactive({
    email: '',
    fname: '',
    course: '',
    phone: '',
});
```

and then send this object's values to your API. For example:

```html
<template>
    <form action.prevent="sendStuff">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>My Form</legend>
            <div class="entry">
                <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" v-model="param3.fname" id="fname" />
            </div>
            <div class="entry">
                <label for="email">EMail</label>
                <input type="email" v-model="param3.email" id="email">
            </div>
            <button @click.prevent="sendStuff">
                Send Data
            </button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</template>

<script setup>
import { reactive } from 'vue'

const param3 = reactive({
    email: '',
    fname: '',
    course: '',
    phone: '',
});

const sendStuff = () => {
    console.log(param3);

    // TODO: submit form data, as param3, to the back-end 
    // receive asynchronous promise and handle it here
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.entry {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    margin: 4px 2px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @HovercraftFullOfEels explained, `param` is not reactive in your code. Please consider the following option, besides the one presented in their answer:

### Option 3

(a variant of Hovercraft's **Option 2**): use `reactive`, but rather than having using `v-model="param.email"` in template, spread it using `toRefs`, so you could use `v-model="email"`:

```js
import { toRefs, reactive } from 'vue'

// remove `fname`, `email`, `course` and `phone` refs
const param = reactive({
  fname: '',
  email: '',
  course: '',
  phone: ''
})

const { fname, email, course, phone } = toRefs(param)
```